# python why if zero, print ('True ') when zero = 0, it prints nothing?

Tags: python, python-3.x

in python why

```
zero = 0
one = 1
if zero:
  print('True') # this print nothing
if one:
  print('True') # this print True
```

I thought when `zero = 0`, this should be the correct one. should give me `True`, but why nothing? If this is right, why when `if one` , it gives me `True`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `bool(0) == False` and `bool(1) == True`.

Answer (score 3):

Refer to this article: [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html)

Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:

- None
- False
- zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
- any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
- any empty mapping, for example, {}.
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.2.5

All other values are considered true -- so objects of many types are always true.

Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations "or" and "and" always return one of their operands.)

Answer (score 1):

[`bool`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/) is a subtype of `int`.

`bool` has two values, `True` and `False`, you can think about them as just "customized" versions of the integers 1 and 0, that only print themselves differently.

`True` and `False` behaves as 1 and 0, except that it redefines `str` and `repr` to display them differently.

```
>>> type(True)
<class 'bool'>
>>> isinstance(True, int)
True

>>> True == 1
True
```

Comment: It's actually not entirely relevant that `0 == False` and `1 == True`, rather, all objects are *truthy or falsey*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to complete the other answers. Here's a [good post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false) for an additional reference.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "subtype" but `True` and `False` are [standalone](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d905df766c367c350f20c46ccd99d4da19ed57d8/Include/boolobject.h#L21) objects.